# React Click events not firing on mobile

Tags: reactjs

I've been working with react for a couple of months now, but have just run into something a little weird.

Click events aren't being fired at all on mobile devices:

http://jsbin.com/morarewelu/1/edit?html,js,output

http://jsbin.com/morarewelu/1/ - Check on your device

You can see that the click is never fired. Testing on iphone here.

Is this expected behaviour, or simply a bug?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There are a few issues in React's Github project which might be helpful.

- [onClick on mobile not fired](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2055)
- [MobileSafariClickEventPlugin requires touch events to be initialized](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1169)

Looks like, you need to add a CSS `cursor:'pointer'` so that mobile phones (iOS devices specifically) fire native click event on the element.

Comment: Just came around the issue and on one of above links I found that you need to add a CSS property `cursor: pointer;` to the element and then it will fire `onClick` on touch events. Just to make it easy - worked for me.

Comment: Yea for me also `cursor: pointer;` works just fine. I mean 'pointer' without quotation marks... Also as I have noticed this is an issue only on IOS devices not Android.

Comment: The cursor css property does not work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, where I need to double click to get any click event to fire. It's not limited to Safari. I was able to overcome this by using onMouseDown and onMouseUp instead - which works on both mobile and desktop - but this is not always convenient. I would like to know why this is happening and how to solve it in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when using Chrome browser, but when I used Firefox the onClick handler was working fine and thus the issue was in Chrome because chrome made some breaking changes for handling touches and because I was preventing default and handling it myself it wasn't working.
Try `running in Firefox` it will work.