# I can't click an area map if it is created with `React`?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating an `image` with `areamap`s to make each one clickable.  Here is the code to render my imagemap:

```
render() {
    var areas = this.renderArea();
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <canvas ref="canvas" ></canvas>
                <img ref="image" src={this.props.source} alt="Missing" useMap="woody" />
            </div>
            <map ref="map" name="#woody">
                {areas}
            </map>
        </div>
    )
}

renderArea() {
    return this.state.mapping.map((area, i) => {
        return <area shape="poly" coords={area} href=""  alt="" title="" onMouseOver={this.mouseOver} onMouseOut={this.mouseOut} onClick={this.onClick}/>
    });
}
```

On desktop, when I hover over the `areamap`, everything works like it should.  When I look at it on my `iPhone`, I can't click on the `areas`.  I found this [`StackOverflow`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525228/react-click-events-not-firing-on-mobile), but when I added `cursor: pointer` it didn't work.  I tried adding to the `area`, `img` and `canvas`, together and separately, but it still didn't work.  It is like the `SO` post said and the `onClick` is not registering.  What else do I do?

Comment: Might be worth checking out React's touch events, if not already? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#touch-events

Comment: I added the touch events and that didn't work

Comment: I see `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut`, but not `onClick` - is that in there, or only the over/out functions?

Comment: The `onClick` was in there, I just missed it when posting the code.

Comment: Late to the party. Did you ever solve this problem?