# Button click requires double click or long-press on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

I'm trying to click a button in a React app, and while it works on desktop, it does not work properly on mobile. I need to long-press or double-click, and play a little bit until the button finally works.

I have replicated my problem in this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-colden-gk79q?file=/src/App.js).

If you open the page on a desktop browser and attempt to open the hamburger menu, it should open right away. However, if you open it in mobile, it will not work right away. You will also see the menu jitter a little bit off-screen. Attempting to close the menu by clicking on the overlay has the same problem in mobile.

**Why is this not working properly on mobile? How can I get the button to work when I tap it?**

I added `cursor:pointer` to the button after seeing this somewhat similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525228/react-click-events-not-firing-on-mobile), but this doesn't help.

This problem has occurred in the past to me, and I was able to solve it using `onMouseDown` but it doesn't work this time, I'm guessing because I'm using a component that is imported from a package (`react-burger-menu`) and can't override its `onClick` function? I'm not sure what is happening.

EDIT: Solved. See my answer.

Comment: Seems to work fine on my mobile, what browser are you trying it on?

Comment: Safari and Google Chrome on iOS. You?

Comment: @brienna You probably have an issue with how you stack html elements

Comment: Chrome on Android, from what I gather all browsers on IOS use Safaris rendering engine.  As a web developer, Microsoft used to be the browser that caused most issues,  unfortunately Apple has now taken that title.  As a company we now advice customers not to invest in Apple, and I think that's a shame, they make great products, but politics is destroying it.

Comment: I think you may be right @aleksa_95. If I remove all the code for the map, leaving just the navbar, it works.

Comment: @brienna just looked at your sandbox and that's the issue. The easiest solution would be just to copy paste your NavBar to App and wrap it in a Fragment. I can look it up more tmrw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it works if I fix the stacking of elements. I had nested my navbar component inside the MapContainer, but this was making things wonky mobile-side. I moved my component outside the MapContainer, and things worked.

I still don't understand why it went wonky mobile-side and in iOS only, but this problem at least is solvable.

Fixed example is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-browser-wxb82?file=/src/App.js).

*My map token has been removed, so you can use your own to substitute, but it is not necessary to have the map showing to see the problem/solution.*

Comment: Any general solution for this?